# Packing number of sparse vectors

Tags: packing-and-covering

The packing number is defined as follows (defintion 4.2.4 [here](https://www.math.uci.edu/%7Ervershyn/papers/HDP-book/HDP-book.pdf)):

A subset $K$ of a normed space $(\mathbb{X},\Vert\cdot\Vert)$ is called $\epsilon$-separated, if $\Vert x-y\Vert> \epsilon$ for all distinct points $x,y \in K$. The packing number $P(M,\Vert\cdot\Vert,\epsilon$) of a set $M \subset \mathbb{X}$ is the largest cardnality of a set $K\subseteq M$ such that $K$ is $\epsilon$-separated.

I am looking for results on lower bounds on the packing number of a set consisting of points which are at most $k$-sparse and lie in a unit Euclidean ball in $d$ dimensions. Formally, define

$$M=\left\{x \in \mathbb{R}^d: \Vert x\Vert_2\leq 1 \text{ and } \Vert x\Vert_{0} \leq k \right\}$$

I am looking for lower bounds on $P(M,\Vert \cdot\Vert_2,\epsilon)$.

I searched online for this but could only find results on upper bounds on the covering number of above set (see discussion after Eqn. (1) [here](https://www.math.uci.edu/%7Ervershyn/papers/role-of-sparsity-RMT.pdf)). It would be of great help if somebody can provide references on this or provide a sketch of a lower bound.

Comment: please write in the definition of packing number into the question

Comment: Sorry about that, just added the definition.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it's still useful, but you can find such a construction here (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1104.5246.pdf, Lemma 2). It is a generalization of the existence proof of dense packings based on the probabilistic method.